# Javascript on change for checkbox

Tags: javascript

I am changing state of check boxes with following code:

```
document.getElementById('checkall').onclick = function(){
     inputs = VARIABLE.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
     for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) 
          inputs[i].checked = true; 
}
```

This section work fine.

and i am creating checkboxes with(these codes call on for):

```
mainFrameInput = document.createElement("input"); mainFrameInput.className = "item"; mainFrameInput.style.display='none'; mainFrameInput.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox'); mainFrameInput.setAttribute('id', GnId);
```

this section work fine too

At this time i want to have a function which run when check boxes changed because it can change on several way.

I am creating check boxes with JavaScript and want to handle onchange with JavaScript NOT JQUERY.

I tested CHECKBOX_VARIABLE.onchange = function{} but it does not call when i change with above code and just CHECKBOX_VARIABLE.onclick work when i click on each checkbox.

I found solution and posted as answer.

Comment: I understand that you want to delegate `change` event with vanilla JavaScript, correct?

Comment: VARIABLE is like this VARIABLE = document.getElementByID('#div-id'); in fact it has some checkboxes

Comment: @AdamAzad yes correct

Comment: @MajidAbbasi trigger the event manually `element.onchange()`.... for eg : `for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
if(!inputs[i].checked){
          inputs[i].checked = true; inputs[i].onchange()} }`

Comment: @MajidAbbasi `D` should be lowercase at `document.getElementByID`; e.g, `VARIABLE = document.getElementById('#div-id');`

Comment: VARIABLE = document.getElementByID('#div-id'); this is for sample, that section work fine

Comment: _"that section work fine"_ `D` is `d` at the actual `javascript` you tried?

Comment: @guest271314 the problem is that i am creating checkboxes with javascript, and change state with javascript which i put in my question. i want to call a function when checkboxes which i created changed with top js

Comment: _"i am creating checkboxes with javascript"_ How are checkboxes created? Dynamically?

Comment: @guest271314 i edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY I RESOLVED THE ISSUE:

first of all i developed a function:

```
    function fireEvent(element,event){
    if (document.createEventObject){
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
    }
    else{
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

and called that when changed state of check box:

```
fireEvent(inputs[i],'change');
```

and added on change event when creating check boxes:

```
mainFrameInput.onchange = function(){ 
        if (this.checked)
        {
            console.log('checked');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('un checked');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

one way to do this is by using the native onchange attribute and give it a function

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="alert('change')">
<option value="Audi">Audi</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
<option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

here's a fiddle showing this

https://jsfiddle.net/r4aj8zh2/

Comment: In fact i want to use that for checkboxes! but your answer is for selectbox.
and i want to apply function on javascript not HTML!

Comment: @MajidAbbasi - This example shows *inline-javascript* (`onchange="alert('change')"`).

Comment: this solution does not word for check box change which i explained

Comment: @MajidAbbasi - undisputed, hence unmentioned. ;)

Comment: @Seif Sayed thank you for your answer, i found solution and posted in my question

Answer (score 4):

You can do this like that:

HTML:

```
<button id="checkall">check all</button><br>
a: <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a"><br>
b: <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b"><br>
c: <input type="checkbox" name="c" value="c">
```

JavaScript:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

document.getElementById('checkall').onclick = function(){
     for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
          inputs[i].checked = true; 
     }
     somethingChanged();
}

for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', somethingChanged);
}

function somethingChanged(evt) {
  if (evt) {
    console.log(evt.srcElement.name, 'changed');
  }
  else {
    console.log('all changed');
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1m3rcvw9/

Explanation: When I tried it I could reproduce your problem - the change listener was not called when clicking the check-all button. So my idea is to just call the function manually after a click occurs on check-all. You can even distinguish between single checkbox clicks and check-all clicks by checking if there is a event-parameter.

EDIT: If you dynamically add `<input>` tags then just add the *somethingChanged* change listener right after creation of new elements and update the inputs variable by reselecting all checkboxes:

```
mainFrameInput = document.createElement("input");  
mainFrameInput.addEventListener('change', somethingChanged);
// ... insert the element into DOM here
inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i found solution and posted in my question

Answer (score 2):

You can `addEventListener` to these checkboxes

```
   // Get all checkbox. Use more specific selector using name or class
   var getAllCheckBox = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
    // Adding event listener change to each checkbox
    getAllCheckBox.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        if (getAllCheckBox.checked) {
            // do something if checked
        } else {
            // do something else otherwise
        }
    });
```

Comment: addEventListener should use when i create checkboxes with javascript or when i am changing state of checkboxes?

Comment: thank you for your answer, i found solution and posted in my question

Answer (score 1):

Add event listener to element when element is created. Make sure the `D` is lower case `d` at `.getElementById` `VARIABLE = document.getElementById('#div-id');`

```
mainFrameInput = document.createElement("input");
mainFrameInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // do stuff
})
```

Comment: does call work when i change checkboxes with javascript

Comment: Yes, if your `javascript` does not have other issues and `D` is lowercase `d` at `VARIABLE = document.getElementById('#div-id');`. Each newly created `<input>` element should have `click` event attached, and you should be able to use first block of `javascript` at Question to trigger `change` event at `click` of `#checkall` element

Comment: i checked other issues several times, when i click on check all it work fine and check checkboxes but mainFrameInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // do stuff
}) does not fire !

Comment: @MajidAbbasi _"but mainFrameInput.addEventListener("change", function() { // do stuff }) does not fire !"_ Did you include `javascript` within handler? Or is there only `// do stuff` within handler? Try substituting `console.log("change")` for comment `// do stuff`. If there is still an issue, try creating a stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to reproduce issue.

Comment: i added console.log("change")

Comment: _"i added console.log("change")"_ Is `"change"` logged to `console` when element state has changed?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: @MajidAbbasi Can you reproduce the issue at stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ or  plnkr http://plnkr.co? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @MajidAbbasi Just noticed `mainFrameInput.setAttribute('id', GnId)`. Are there duplicate `id`'s in document? Note, `id` of element in document should be unique, see [`Element.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

Comment: thank you for your answer, i found solution and posted in my question

Comment: If you have resolved Question, and none of the posted Answers solved your issue, you can post an Answer to your own Question, and accept your own Answer, instead of including your solution at the Question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: OK Sure, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more easy just define a `onchange` function into the `input` element like this:

```js
const wrapperElement = document.querySelector('.wrapper')
const fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

fruits.forEach(f => {
  const item = document.createElement('div')
  item.className = 'item'

  const fruit = document.createElement('input')
  fruit.type = 'checkbox'
  fruit.id = f
  fruit.onchange = handleOnChange

  const label = document.createElement('label')
  label.className = 'checkbox-label'
  label.setAttribute('for', f)
  label.textContent = f


  item.append(fruit)
  item.append(label)

  wrapperElement.append(item)
})


function handleOnChange(e) {
  const element = e.srcElement
  element.parentElement.classList.toggle('checked')
}
```

```css
.item.checked {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```